# pandas - how to work with arrays in cells

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with arrays. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('a', [1,2,3]), ('b', [4,5,6])], columns=['name', 'values'])

  name     values
0    a  [1, 2, 3]
1    b  [4, 5, 6]
```

I know that the `values` col arrays are of the same length.
I want to calculate the average on axis=0 of the values arrays.
In numpy I could do it like:

```
np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]).mean(axis=0) # result: array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

Is it possible with plain pandas?
If not, how can I easily convert the values col to a numpy array?
I've tried `df['values'].values`, but this does not gives a matrix:

```
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 5):

use pandas  series.tolist for converting pandas series to list

```
np.array(df['values'].tolist()).mean(axis = 0)

#o/p
array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

Comment: This works, but tolist() is a bit slow. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one column you want to work on, You can use `apply` on the relevant column. `apply` on a `pd.Series` (e.g. column) works per element.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('a', [1,2,3]), ('b', [4,5,6])], columns=['name', 'values'])
df['values_mean'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=0))
df
```

Yields:

```
    name    values  values_mean
0   a   [1, 2, 3]   2.0
1   b   [4, 5, 6]   5.0
```

If you have more than one column, the `applymap` function works on a `pd.DataFrame` per element (instead of `apply` on a dataframe, which works per column). For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('a', [1,2,3]), ('b', [4,5,6])], columns=['name', 'values'])
df[['values']].applymap(lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=0))
```

Yields:

```
    values
0   2.0
1   5.0
```

Comment: wrong axis, see desired result in question `array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist()).mean()
Out[336]: 
0    2.5
1    3.5
2    4.5
dtype: float64
```